Example Needed for "Directories With A Common Name Hiding Modules"
When I read Python 3's documentation for modules, in 6.4 Packages, it said (emphasis mine):

The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories
containing the file as packages (unless using a namespace package, a
relatively advanced feature). This prevents directories with a
common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid
modules that occur later on the module search path.

Can anybody give an example to explain what the bolded part means?

That, for example, a directory named string next to your Python file won't break importing the standard library string module.
Consider:
- my_script.py
- string/

and
import string
print(string)

in that my_script.py.
If the described behavior wasn't the case, import string in my_script.py would try to import the "local" string package – you can verify this by adding an __init__.py and seeing how things change.
For instance, in a fresh Docker container:
/work# cat > my_script.py
import string
print(string)
/work# python3 my_script.py
<module 'string' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/string.py'>
/work# mkdir string
/work# python3 my_script.py
<module 'string' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.12/string.py'>
/work# touch string/__init__.py
/work# python3 my_script.py
<module 'string' from '/work/string/__init__.py'>
/work#

